# WCF Service Reference and iNotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wcf, inotifypropertychanged

I have a boolean property called IsUpdated in my base class which I want to set to TRUE when any property in my objects gets changed in the client.

My base class is something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class EntityBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IAuditable
{
    #region Data Members
    [DataMember]
    public int Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsUpdated
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        IsUpdated = true;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

All my classes derive from this class.  If this were not in WCF service, it'll be just fine.  But of course, after I add a service reference to my WCF service, my PropertyChanged event handler and the SetField method do not get copied to the client.

Visual Studio automatically implements INotifyPropertyChanged for my WCF Service DataContracts, but what do I do so that IsUpdated is set to TRUE whenever a property in a derived class gets modified?

Comment: Can you post some of your code?  What do your `DataContract`s look like, and what is the "base class" that you refer to?

Comment: WCF contracts are about *data*, not *behaviour*, so send just data to the client. Add a conversion on the client from a POCO/DTO object (without behaviour) to an entity (with behaviour).

Comment: "Add a conversion on the client from a POCO/DTO object (without behaviour) to an entity (with behaviour)."  ---> what does this mean?